# How chrome executable autorun?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, security

So, on http://google.com/chrome/ you can download chrome.
You chose chrome channel and accept EULA. 
Web installer starts download and after few seconds autolaunch itself and  immediatly starts installing chrome (!)
No Windows popups "Are you sure that you want launch executable?". Just starts.

How it done? It also written on GWT, is it matter?
Or maybe it because executable signed by google? But in that way it's cant autorun, just downloads and starts only by clicking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome uses a .NET ClickOnce installer, which can be autostarted from IE. Note that in case of other browsers (confirmed for Firefox), you explicitly have to download the .exe, just like any other executable file.

As for not asking for elevated rights, it's because it installs itself to your user's folder, not in Program Files.

Comment: I have Windows 7 machine, and chrome is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: Okay, I guess I really didn't mention that with admin rights, it's possible to install it system-wide, but it's more than happy to live in your AppData folder. (And answering the question: how can it install itself without asking for permission.)

Comment: How on earth does IE know that the installer is safe?

Comment: It doesn't; it asks for conformation, as seen on this image: http://mcaf.ee/mxf98

Comment: @MátéGelei: OK, that makes more sense, and that's what I saw when I tried it.  Based on the OP's question, though, he didn't get that dialog.  Perhaps his IE security settings have gotten mangled somehow.